# Show that if $\ddot{u} + b\dot{u} + cu = g(t)$ and $g(t)$ is analytic, then so is $u$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So, I need to show that if $\ddot{u} + b\dot{u} + cu = g(t)$ and $g(t)$ is analytic, then so is $u$. I can see that $u$ must be smooth (since it is at least $n+2$ times continuously differentiable if $g(t)$ is $n$ times continuously differentiable, but I have no idea how to show its analyticity in general.

I have tried to rewrite $g(t)$ as a power series for some neighborhood, but I don't see how I could "distribute" parts of this series divided on $\ddot{u}$, $b\dot{u}$ and $cu$. It doesn't help that the only way to show that a series is analytic is when I know that it is an antiderivative of some analytic function. Could you please help me?

Comment: Assuming $b,c$ are constants, you should be able to recursively solve for power series coefficients (near some point $t_0$...) of $u$, _and_ prove convergence by an induction argument. Such induction argument can get messy, but this one should not be toooo bad.

Comment: there is an integral formula for a particular solution $u$, involving the corresponding Green function or variation of constants, and it is evidently analytical. The general $u$ is this particular $u$ plus a solution of the homogeneous equation, and the latter is certainly analytical.